# Mapping Torus of Klein bottle

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, mapping-class-group

The mapping torus of a Klein bottle $ K $ is a compact flat 3 manifold.

The mapping class group of the Klein bottle $ K $ is the Klein four group $ C_2 \times C_2 $. See proposition 20 of

https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1123

There are exactly four compact flat non-orientable 3 manifolds, one of which is $ K \times S^1 $, the mapping torus of the trivial mapping class of $ K $.

Now for the four compact flat non orientable 3 manifolds. These are distinguished by their first homology $ H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}) $ (see Wolf)
$$
\mathbb{Z}^2 \times C_2, \mathbb{Z}^2, \mathbb{Z}\times C_2 \times C_2, \mathbb{Z} \times C_4
$$
They correspond to the trivial mapping torus $ S^1 \times K $, the mapping torus of the Dehn twist, the mapping torus of the Y homeomorphism and the mapping torus of the Dehn twist plus Y homeomorphism, respectively.

See the wikipedia page for Seifert fibration with positive orbifold euler characteristic.

I'm curious how these homology groups are computed from the geometry of the mapping torus perspective.

Comment: cool question +1 . My guess is no. One flat three manifold is $(S^1)^3$, and by guess is that the long exact sequence in homology will present an obstruction to this working out just for rank of $H_1$ reasons

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963334/homology-groups-of-the-mapping-torus) for the long exact sequence. For example, we should have a long exact sequence $ \tilde{H}_1(K) \to \tilde{H}_1(M_f) \to 0$ . Plugging in the first homology of $(S^1)^3$, we can see that this would give $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z^3 \to 0$, but there is no such surjection.

Comment: @AndresMejia I'm glad you like my question! I'm asking about non-orientable manifolds so not $ (S^1)^3=T^3 $ . There are actually 10 flat compact 3 manifolds, 6 orientable and 4 non orientable. The 6 orientable ones include the torus $ T^3 $ which is the trivial mapping torus of $ T^2 $ as well as the mapping tori of the four other finite order elements of the mapping class group of $ T^2 $ (order 2,3,4,6) and a sixth exceptional compact flat orientable manifold with monodromy $ C_2 \times C_2 $.  I am asking if there is a similar story about the four nonorientable ones and the Klein bottle.

Comment: Oops no doubt. Glad I left it as a comment lol. Maybe there still is some homological obstruction. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420017/mapping-torus-of-klein-bottle